# buttons on bottom of listview dont work

Tags: android, listview, button, layout

I have a listview and would like to have on the buttom of my screen two buttons. the problem is as soon as the list is getting too long the buttons dissapear. What can i do to make the bottons always to be visible?

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
</ExpandableListView>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="do something"
        android:text="some text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="do something"
        android:text="some text" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use relative layout and place buttons at the bottom of it. Set list view as above buttons linearlayout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >


<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttons">
</ExpandableListView>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/buttons"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="do something"
        android:text="some text" />

    <Button

        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="do something"
        android:text="some text" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want to go ahead with linearlayout and weight then set height to 0dp for both linear layout and list:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
</ExpandableListView>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="do something"
        android:text="some text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="do something"
        android:text="some text" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Adjust weights as you need.

Comment: i have tried to do this code (RelativeLayout) .. the buttons gone

Comment: Ok i have somethink wring in my code (y) .. your code is right

Comment: i did try it with relativelayout before too but the problem is that then the last item of the listview is behind the buttons

Answer (score 1):

You can create a layout file only containing your Buttons, then you can add it to your layout as a Footer of your ListView with `ListView.addFooterView()`.

Example:

`LinearLayout footerLayout = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer,null);
mListView.addFooterView(footer);`

Answer (score 0):

You should use relative layout as main/parent layout. then in your child linear layout you can set and attribute saying alignparentbottom="true" and your expandable listview can be aligned above your linear layout, see below for example

```
<RelativeLayout
//Write your other attributes here>

<ExpandableListView
//Write your other attributes here
//add one more atribute and set it to align above the linearlayout>
</ExpandableListView>

<LinearLayout
//Write your other attributes here
//add one attribute alignparent bottom and set it to "true">
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```